# How to read image of a custom form with OCR

Tags: php, ocr

I'm searching for an API (or other solution) that can get selected data from custom and various images of forms. I need, for example, the first name from all the documents. some can be a table with borders of birth certificate, others will be a pdf of a school diploma. There can be many types of different documents. Is there something that is flexible enough?

I've tried using Tesseract OCR. Also tried Google OCR. 
All of them did not work well enough.

Comment: Hi erez! Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Comment: As each and every document is of a separate/different format and type you will never be able to get a generic solution for the same.